# Checking input variables against array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Trying to check input variable (sGuess) against my array (sportsArray) ...

var name  works fine

then when I have it check that variable (sGuess) that the user inputs against the array (sportsArray) I always get the following in console. 
Loop 1 returns NaN
Loop 2 returns undefined
Loop 3 returns it's input perfectly

I am using the following javascript code

```
  var sportsArray = new Array("Football", "Basketball", "Rollerblading", "Hiking", "Biking", "Swimming");
  var name;
  var score;
  var loops;
  var sGuess;

// prompts for user name, checks input.
do {
name = prompt("Enter your first name");
}

while (name == "");


// loop for guesses.
for (var i = 1; i <4; i++) {

// prompts user for guess.
sGuess = prompt("Enter your sports guess");


if(sportsArray.indexOf(sGuess) == -1) {

    alert("Sorry! Guess Again.");
    score -= 5;
}

else {
    alert("You are good, try it again!");
    score += 5;
}
 }
```

How do I fix the loop 1 & 2 returning errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hey You have to initialize a variable first:

```
var sportsArray = new Array("Football", "Basketball", "Rollerblading", "Hiking", "Biking", "Swimming");
var name;
var score;
var loops;
var sGuess;

// prompts for user name, checks input.
do {
 name = prompt("Enter your first name");
}

while (name == "");

// loop for guesses.
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

 // prompts user for guess.
 sGuess = prompt("Enter your sports guess");
var s = sportsArray.indexOf(sGuess);
 if (s == -1) {

   alert("Sorry! Guess Again.");
   score -= 5;
 } else {
   alert("You are good, try it again!");
   score += 5;
 }
}
```

Comment: I switched it to your solution and im still getting the same console errors when i run it.

Comment: I tried solution with open Console and it doesn't throw any errors: https://jsfiddle.net/umzvteyw/

Comment: if you do an alert(score); if returns nothing. if you do an alert(sGuess) it only returns the 1st inputted sport.

Comment: try to initialize these variables: var name = "";
var sGuess = "";
var score = 0;